# How to install stripped-down Windows on Chromebook

Tags: boot, bios, operating-systems, chromebook, intel

I'm using Asus CX1400CN Chromebook. My idea is to use Tiny11 or Tiny10 on a Chromebook without removing ChromeOS. Is this possible?

The problem with Windows 10 or 11 is that they require UEFI, whereas my Chromebook uses legacy BIOS.

Comment: Windows 10 does not require UEFI.

Comment: @gronostaj True for PCs but the consensus seems to be it is indeed required (via custom firmwares) for Chromebooks.

Comment: If not mentioned here https://coolstar.org/chromebook/windows.html then it isn't supported yet. That seems to be the case of your specific model. So the answer at the time of this writing is "no, not possible".

Answer (score 0):

Try to Install the "Full ROM" version of the Mr. Chromebox firmware.
https://mrchromebox.tech/#firmware

this should allow you to boot into UEFI bios instead of legacy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).